# munging inconsistent data in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have several sets of data, comprising about 3,000,000 measurements each. In many cases, 'identical' tests yielded different results. I am trying to create a scheme such that these inconsistencies are apparent in the processed data. I am using pandas for my analyses.

Though not my real case, here is a similar example: Suppose I have a set of chemicals, A, B, C, ..., and I mix them together pairwise and note whether a reaction takes place. Let's denote no reaction by '0' and a measurable reaction by '1'. Our data might look like this:

| chemical 1 | chemical 2 | Do they react? | comments |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | B | 1 | comment 1 |
| D | E | 0 | comment 2 |
| A | B | 1 | comment 3 |
| F | G | 1 | comment 4 |
| A | B | 0 | comment 5 |

I am thinking that a workable aim would be to use a sentinel (say, '2') to indicate this inconsistency and summarize the comments for later examination:

| chemical 1 | chemical 2 | Do they react? | comments |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | B | 2 | comment 1; comment 3; comment 5 |
| D | E | 0 | comment 2 |
| F | G | 1 | comment 4 |

I have developed code to identify the tuples (chemical 1, chemical 2) that lead to these inconsistent results. There are about 30,000 of them in my first dataset. This calculation runs fairly quickly.

I have also created some pandas code to give me the desired dataframe. Here is an adaptation for the type of data above:

```py
def uniquify_rows(df, replicates, sentinel=2):
    for chemical_1, chemical_2 in replicates:
        indices = (df["chemical 1"] == chemical_1) & (df["chemical 2"] == chemical_2)
        rows = df[indices]
        comments = ";".join(c for c in rows["comments"].values)
        field_vals = rows.iloc[0].values # chem1, chem2, react, comments
        field_vals[2], field_vals[3] = sentinel, comments 
        df.iloc[indices] = field_vals

    df.drop_duplicates(inplace=True)

    return df
```

This code seems to work on my data, but is extremely slow. Being relatively new to pandas, I suspect that I am doing something very inefficient.

Any ideas to speed up this task?

Thank you.

Kind regards,
gyro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's try with [`groupby aggregate`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.aggregate.html#pandas-core-groupby-dataframegroupby-aggregate):

```
sentinel = 2
df = df.groupby(['chemical 1', 'chemical 2'], as_index=False).aggregate({
    'Do they react?': lambda s: s.iat[0] if (s.iat[0] == s).all() else sentinel,
    'comments': ';'.join
})
```

`df`:

```
  chemical 1 chemical 2  Do they react?                       comments
0          A          B               2  comment 1;comment 3;comment 5
1          D          E               0                      comment 2
2          F          G               1                      comment 4
```